# How should I verify email address existence and domain name existence in javascript or nodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, email-validation, email-verification

I have tried so many npm packages to verify the email address and domain name.
Here are the some of the npm packages I have tried

```
email-check,
email-verify,
email-existence, 
legit,
email-validator and,
email validation
```

all these results in domain name existence and some other checks only.
But I have to verify the particular email address exist in the domain. 
How should I achieve this...
*Can anyone pls help me to find it out*
*Thanks in advance!!*

Comment: Just send a `verify link` on the email given by the user and let them verify it. There is a reason this procedure is widely use by most applications.

Comment: yes, I am using that. But I want to check without sending email to the user..That is my concern.

Comment: You can't programmatically verify an email address. The server its at won't for both security and privacy reasons allow that.

Comment: You can try with npm legit, it will be handy to check domain existance, or else you can go with Kick Box validation which is a paid service

Comment: yes,@Gunasekaran I am using kickbox API ..But the requirement is without using That.

Comment: @GunasekaranR KickBox still need the user to verify

Comment: @LGSon, I got your point ...But still I am not satisfied...some inners feelings said that it should have some solution.

Comment: Don't you think all would use that if they could? ... Still no one does, and for a reason. With such solution spammer etc. could traverse all the servers and get every email address on earth available

Comment: @LGSon, okay... Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check mail address is exists or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514005/how-to-check-mail-address-is-exists-or-not)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Today (and probably never) it is not possible to programmatically verify an email address.

The server its at won't for both security and privacy reasons allow that.

And for a good reason. With such solution, spammers etc. could traverse all the servers and get every email address available.

*As a note, there are tools out there that claims being email verification solutons. They generally use DNS validations, including MX record(s) lookup, but they can't with 100% accuracy say if an email address exist or not, they can only get what the email server is setup to give them.*

---

Domain name can be though, and [NSLookup](https://www.google.com/search?q=nslookup&oq=nslookup) is one of the services that can do that.

---

Updated

I found a few good reads at SO (where the first is actually a dupe, though can't close it myself)

- [How to check if an email address exists without sending an email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565504/how-to-check-if-an-email-address-exists-without-sending-an-email?rq=1)
- [How to validate an email address using a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression?rq=1)
- [How to validate an email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks a lot to making me to understand.