# Check if email id exists without sending an email in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, email

I came across [this article](https://www.webdigi.co.uk/blog/2009/how-to-check-if-an-email-address-exists-without-sending-an-email/) describing how an email id can be verified without sending an email in PHP. I was wondering if something similar can be done with node (without using any external package).

I am relatively new to node.js.

Comment: I don't think so any email provider like gmail or yahoo provide these services .

Comment: Its not a service, it is based on establishing a connection with a smtp server. Working demo: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/verify_email_address.htm

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49314277/how-should-i-verify-email-address-existence-and-domain-name-existence-in-javascr

Comment: Not a duplicate, the question provided talks about using external packages. I need to do it without using an external package.