# How Can I Verify Emails for Existance Other Than SMTP Methods

Tags: php, email, smtp, email-verification

I need to clear fake emails from a pile of ~20.000 emails. Sending verification email is not an option on this case since users already signed up.(and most probably don't even remember their password anyway)

I have tried smtp verification but connection attempts to most popular esp's always return connection failed or timeout reached over the port "25" & "587" (i assume they block smtp requests on purpose)

I don't want to use a paid web service since 20k email verifications cost about 150$ (which i can not afford in my current situation)

How can i achieve email verification under these circumstances (TIA)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120350/how-to-check-programmatically-a-email-is-existing-or-not

Comment: duplicate of a post from 5 years ago ? ..

Comment: please check "SR query" answers, hope that will help.

Comment: as i said port 25 and port 587 return connection errors as they are blocked by EPS's.