# How to verify existence of an email address programmatically?

Tags: android, email

I'm new to Android programming and I'm currently working on an app that requires the user to enter a valid email address that is valid in terms of existence in servers and not the syntax. I want something like what the default phone client uses to verify and initialize usage of email addresses.

Comment: you need web service to check email id is valid or not to communicate with the server.

Comment: @farhana how exactly do I do that?

Comment: And I also don't get why I've been down voted

Comment: your web developer give you URL or API or web service where you can post your email id and the server will respond you that email id is valid or not. I think you have to learn about asyn task,volley are the ways to communicate to the server, In which you web URL is passed to communicate

Comment: Ok ill look into that though its still a bit unclear but ill get back to you.

Comment: can you check this link, It will help you to learn how to communicate to the server http://androidtechpoint.blogspot.in/2017/01/android-app-for-login-sign-up-using-volley-and-php.html

Comment: nothings helping.Ive been looking around and some apps are using smtp to do this.Anyone with an idea on how to implement this?

Comment: I dont have a server to confirm the emails from so i want something thatll check against other servers for existence of emails.Or at least some other way to do it.Please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check programmatically if an email is existing or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120350/how-to-check-programmatically-if-an-email-is-existing-or-not)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this service's API: https://market.mashape.com/mr_admin/email-verifier. Note, it's a paid service for >20 checks/day, which might rule it out, but on the plus side, they've done a lot of work for you. Note that no method is going to be 100% accurate.

Comment: @ankitaggarwal how do you mean?

Comment: i mean that if i assume my company email id i.e., private mail id, if this email id is identified by any `API` , how could you say it is private mail id or secure.

Comment: @ankitaggarwal true of course, but that's a limitation of _any _ API, as you say.

Comment: It's as right as any answer can be, unless you want me to say, "it can't be done", despite the fact that there's a service that provides a solution for all the public emails in the world, which is the vast majority of them! And then I note your answer also suggests the OP calls an API!

Answer (score 0):

To check if email exists or not from server end, you can hit API and API will return if email is already exists or not.

Comment: please elaborate.I don't quite get you